# How to get div's selector using this

Tags: javascript, selector

so I want to get div's selector by using $(this) via JQuery
How to do this? Will it be something like that? $("... this")

```
<div id="divId">
     <span onclick="myFunction()">Some Text</span>
     <span onclick="myFunction()">Some Text</span>
     <span onclick="myFunction()">Some Text</span>
     <span onclick="myFunction()">Some Text</span>
</div>
<script>
myFunction(){
selector im asking for.doSomething();
}

</script>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as “_the_ selector”, any HTML element can be selected using countless different ways. Do you actually mean you want to get the value `divId`? (And if so, what for?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get parent's id:

```
myFunction(){
  $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
}
```

Drop `.attr('id')` if you need to get the div itself:

```
myFunction(){
   $(this).parent('div');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an id for the div, you can simply do `$('#divId')` to select the div.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```js
$('#divId').click(function(){
$(this).hide();
})
```